# Serialize not picking up Select options - JSFiddle

Tags: jquery, serialization

I'm having a fight with the Serialize code on the JSFiddle below, it's not picking up the select options available in the form? It's picking up the text inputs well enough however the 'select' is not appearing. The code excludes empty fields but the select option is never empty?

[JQuery Serialize](http://jsfiddle.net/4Nmcx/173/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have the select blocked rather than including it try this

```
$('#form1').find('select,input[type="text"]').not('#url').change(function(){
    var val = "";
    var url = '/static/url/to/file.php?';
    $('form select,input[type="text"]:not("input#url")').each(function(){
        if ($.trim(this.value).length > 0 ) {
          val += ($(this).attr('name') + "" + this.value + "&");
        }  
    })
    $('#url').val(url+val);
});

$('#button').click(function(){
    window.location= $('#url').val();
});
```

[WORKING DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/7AJya/)

Comment: Hi mcgrailm...the working demo doesn't seem to be working in IE (browser at work)...is it working in Firefox?

Comment: yeah thats what I tested it in ... odd that it doesn't work in ie

Comment: Nice one...I'll give it a whirl on FF when I get out of work.

Answer (score 0):

You  can try $('#form1').serialize() and put the field url out of the form